# Exception during StringFormat: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, string.format

I have seen few examples like this on site but all are having errors with the place holders being named wrong or having differences in number of parameters and place holders , my logline is like below

```
Logger.InfoFormat("Successfully connected to outgoing queue for platform {0}. QueueManagerName = {1}, HostName = {2}, ChannelName = {3}, QueueName = {4}", Platform.ID, Platform.MqGatewayParams.QueueManagerName, Platform.MqGatewayParams.HostName, Platform.MqGatewayParams.ChannelName, Platform.MqGatewayParams.OutgoingQueueName);
```

The InfoFormat method :

```
public void InfoFormat(string className, string methodName, string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        _log4NetLogger.InfoFormat(GetMessageString(className, methodName, format), arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
```

and internally it calls GeMessageString

```
private string GetMessageString(string className, string methodName, object message)
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}::{1}] {2}", className ?? string.Empty, methodName ?? " ", message ?? " ");
    }
```

Can any body tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: the one i have given topic "Exception during StringFormat: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

Comment: Are you sure this is the signature of your `InfoFormat` method? Because if  that's true, you totally messed up the parameters when calling it.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Thanks alot buddy , mind was totally out got the issue your one line made my day :) , yes i just messed up with parameters

Answer (score 2):

In the `InfoFormat` method you have:

> ```
> _log4NetLogger.InfoFormat(GetMessageString(className, methodName, format), arg0, arg1, arg2);
> ```

This is only passing 3 format arguments to `_log4NetLogger.InfoFormat`, but your format string has 5.

You need to make use of `params` for variable length parameter lists, like this:

```
void FormatString(string format, params object[] args) {
  String.Format(format, args)
}
```

(There is a small benefit of providing overloads for shorter parameter lists – use `String.Format` itself as an example – as the allocation of an array is not needed; but it is a small optimisation unless these functions are used a lot.)

PS. The sample caller seems to be passing a format string as the first argument of your `InfoFormat`, but its implementation appears to be expecting parameters to look up the string.